# How to connect to server using SockJS

Tags: google-chrome-extension, sockjs

I need to connect to a socketJS server using client library in a chrome extension. I'm able to connect but I have some trouble to send the needed data to the server. I've added the `wss://*` protocol into my `manifest.json` file. In my vue methods I have a method with this code, but it seems that no data are sended to the server after connection. Is there any fix for this?

```
      const ws = new SockJS(info.wschat_host)
      console.log(ws)
      ws.onopen = (e) => {
        console.log(e)
        const connData = {
          method: 'connect',
          data: {
            user: info['chat_username'],
            password: info['chat_password'],
            room_info: info['broadcaster_username'],
            room_password: info['room_pass']
          }
        }
        const d = JSON.stringify(connData)
        console.log(d)
        console.log('connected')

        ws.send(d)
        const roomInfo = {
          method: 'joinRoom',
          data: {
            room: info['broadcaster_username']
          }
        }
        const r = JSON.stringify(roomInfo)
        console.log(r)
        ws.send(r)
        ws.onmessage = (e) => {
          console.log('message', e.data)
        }
      }
```

Comment: show server code please

Comment: @frozen Unfortunately I don't have the server code, I need to connect to a third part chat service and they are using SockJS on the server. I think that it can be a client side problem but not sure, if I log the `ws.send()` it will result in an undefined in console

Comment: show console logs?